# Converting DTO to entity object and vice-versa using Spring Converter

Tags: java, spring, converters, dto

I need to convert `DTO` to corresponding `Hibernate entities` and vice-versa and my application is Spring based. I came to know that Spring provides `Converter` interface which can be used.

I don't understand the advantage of using `Spring Converter` over frameworks like `Dozer` or manual get and set.

Also, how does `Spring converter` helps me in converting DTOs to Hibernate entities and vice-versa.

Comment: use ModelMapper class in spring  for converting. see here: http://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application